# Adding a Dropdown Menu Bootstrap Instant 4

Tags: 2sxc

Not sure this is place for it but its a 2SXC theme so I assumed maybe this is the best bet.

New to the DNN module but what is the easiest way to get a dropwdown menu going with the bootstrap menu 4

I see using

```
    <dnn:MENU MenuStyle="nav/main" NodeSelector="*,0,6" runat="server" />
```

Gives me all my children, but how do i edit the styles or is this a built in menu with drop down in this theme?

Answer (score 0):

DNN uses a template to create the HTML for the menu. You can find this template in the nav/main folder in your theme directory. ([root]/Portals/_default/[THEMENAME]/nav/main)

I don't have any experience with the 2SXC themes, but many themes have the HTML template in .txt file. There is also likely a CSS file in there. However, the CSS for the menu may be located in the skin.css file.